# Update table after certain time in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel, I want to update a table status to active at certain time for eg: my table column date value '2019-03-20 12:10:00' when the time is crossed '2019-03-20 12:10:00' then status column has to be updated to active automatically. Please anyone provide me the solution.

Comment: Use Task Scheduling together with a cron entry on your server: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Task Scheduling

```
$schedule->command('auto:active')->dailyAt('12:10');
```

You can schudele command based on your logic. it will triggered `12:10` daily

Your command will look something like

```
class AutoActive extends Command
{
   protected $signature = 'auto:active';
   protected $description = 'your desc.....';

   public function handle()
   {
      // you can write your logic here
   }
}
```

For more info read: [Scheduling artisan commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands)

Comment: Hi Bhavinjr, Thank you for your suggestion, as you have mentioned as "it will triggered 12:10 daily". It's not daily activity when the date will have different time like 12:10, 12:40 likewise.

Comment: Moreover I'm trying on  localhost in window 7 OS on PC

Comment: Thank you Bhavinjr, I was able to update the column.